# Edit a MSSQL table from web

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying find out what is the best solution for making a single table in a MSSQL database available for insert and update for a few users from a html interface.

I've got IIS server, reporting services, C#, visual studio and most microsoft tools of the 2008 version.

In php/mysql I would deploy a framework for editing tables. Whats the easiest MS solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to perform edit, delete operation on front end, you can use grid view tool from asp.net.

you can find details at the following link,
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: works brilliant, just needed to change the sql statements for the test to work. Many thanks!